# ¿Cómo hacer que la semana empiece en lunes? PHP

Tags: php, date

Necesito que la semana empiece en lunes en un archivo php, pero me detecta que empieza en domingo.

```
<?php
//setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");

$dayotw = date('w');
$start = date('W');
$today = date('j');
$name = date('l');

echo('Num day of the week current:');
echo ($dayotw);
echo "<br>";
echo('Today:');
echo($today);
echo "<br>";
echo('Name current day:');
echo($name);
echo "<br>";
echo('Start the week:');
echo($start);

?>
```

En el archivo php me sale esto:

```
Num day of the week current:5
Today:26
Name current day:Friday
Start the week:21
```

Como podeis ver en Start the week, me sale 21, el pasado domingo, me gustaría que empezara el 22 (lunes).

Comment: Respuesta añadida y completada con ejemplos y explicación de cómo obtener el día de la semana en formato local. Espero que te sea de ayuda. Para cualquier duda déjame un comentario en la respuesta.

Comment: @Xerif eso soluciona que el día de la semana `w` (minúscula, no mayúscula como has interpretado) sea del rango 0 (domingo) al 6 (sábado), cambiando del 1 (lunes) al 7 (domingo), pero no soluciona su pregunta, el cálculo del día del mes en el que empieza la semana. El problema está en que `W` no hace lo que él esperaba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás cometiendo un error, el valor que devuelve `W` en la función [`date()`](http://php.net/function.date) no es el día de la semana en el que empieza la semana, si no:

> **W:** Número de la semana del año **ISO-8601**, las semanas comienzan en lunes. Ejemplo: 42 (la 42ª semana del año)

El número 21 es el número de semana, no el día del mes.

A mí, personalmente, me gusta más usar la funcionalidad de la [`clase DateTime`](http://php.net/class.datetime).

Para obtener el día en el que empieza la semana debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$fecha = new DateTime('last monday');
/* O tras haberla creado: */
//$fecha->modify('last monday');
echo 'Start the week: ', $fecha->format('d'), PHP_EOL;
```

En la cadena del constructor o bien en el método [`modify()`](http://php.net/datetime.modify) puedes indicarle que obtenga la fecha del último lunes y posteriormente usar `format()` para darle formato de manera similar a `date()`.

Aquí tienes la documentación acerca del [formato de definición relativa de fechas](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative).

Tu código completo sería:

```
<?php
$fecha = new DateTime();
$dayotw = $fecha->format('w');
$today = $fecha->format('j');
$name = $fecha->format('l');
/* A partir de ahora $fecha apuntará al lunes pasado si no estamos en lunes */
if ($fecha->format('w') !== '1') {
  $fecha->modify('last monday');
}
$start = $fecha->format('d');
?>
<p>Num day of the week current: <?= $dayotw ?></p>
<p>Today: <?= $today ?></p>
<p>Name current day: <?= htmlspecialchars($name) ?></p>
<p>Start the week: <?= $start ?></p>
```

Por último, si deseas tener un día de la semana en el formato local deseado deberías usar [`strftime()`](http://php.net/function.strftime) en lugar de `DateTime::format()` o `date`:

```
<?php
/* ... Sólo modificar esta línea ... */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8', 'es_ES', 'es');
$name = strftime('%A', $fecha->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: Hola, has resuelto parte de mi duda, pero también me gustaría que en el numero "Num day of the week current:" debería salir un 4 no? Porque empieza a contar des del 0, y el viernes que es hoy seria 4.

Comment: No es así. Si ves el [enlace que te proporcioné](http://php.net/function.date), pone esto: "0 (para domingo) hasta 6 (para sábado)". Es decir, hoy es viernes, sale un "5". Si usas `N` entonces será 1 para lunes y 7 para domingo.

Comment: Si tienes más dudas no dudes en insistir preguntando, nunca me molestaré por eso :)

Comment: Lo he resuelto de otra forma, pero siguiendo tus pasos:
$date = new DateTime();
$weekstart = $date->modify('last monday')->format('d');

$today = date('j');
$n_dayotw = $today - $weekstart;
$name = date('l');

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Que no se te olvide el `if`, en caso contrario los lunes calculará el lunes anterior. Y esa resta no funciona bien en los cambios de mes, cuidado con ella.

Comment: Cómo podría afrontar ese problema con un `if`?

Comment: ¿El `if` que dices es para lo del lunes anterior o para la resta? Para el primero te puse un ejemplo en el código de la respuesta. Para el segundo no necesitas un `if`, sólo usar `N` en el `date()` y restarle uno si quieres que vaya de 0 (lunes) a 6 (domingo) en vez de 1 (lunes) a 7 (domingo).